# Creating new column of dataframe into global enviroment inside loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

So am I trying to get a new column with the value of the division of two different columns.I'm trying to do this for multiple dfs. I know the loop works without the assign function but unfortunately it doens't save it in the global environment.

`vect` is a vector with multiple data frames

```
for (i in vect) {
      i$new <- i[,2] / i[,3]
      print(i)
}
```

I was looking for a way to rewrite this in a workable manner:

```
assign(i$new, i[,2] / i[,3],envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: please share some data so people can troubleshoot the problem. `lapply` might offer some additional help here. In general you can format your code with ctrl+k, which makes the code more readable

Answer (score 0):

You could cbind the new column into each dataframe in a list using lapply.

```
dfs <- list(df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                              y = c(2,3,4,5,6)),
            df2 <- data.frame(x = c(5,6,7,8,9),
                              y = c(1,3,4,5,6)))

dfs <- lapply(dfs, function(d){
  new <- d$x/d$y
  cbind(d, new)} )

dfs

> dfs
[[1]]
  x y       new
1 1 2 0.5000000
2 2 3 0.6666667
3 3 4 0.7500000
4 4 5 0.8000000
5 5 6 0.8333333

[[2]]
  x y  new
1 5 1 5.00
2 6 3 2.00
3 7 4 1.75
4 8 5 1.60
5 9 6 1.50
```